# How to create random daily notifications in flutter/dart app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, notifications

I have a flutter app coded in dart. I've used firebase as the backend, and currently in the app a user is able to input their age, name and a nice message which is saved in the backend. I have a button, which when pressed, is meant to create a randomly timed daily notification of a random (name, age, message).

My question is, what is the best way to go about this? I've seen online multiple ways to create daily notifications, but I wasn't able to get the first few I tried to work. Is firebase FCM the way to go? Or should I use some background manager?

The app does have streams set up to always get up to date information, and a current button works, which is to display a random message the moment it is pressed.

I've tried some guides, but haven't been able to achieve my intended function

Answer (score 0):

Depend on notification you use.
My recommendation is use `awesome_notification` package for flutter.
if you want just to show local notification, i think you don't need the FCM thing. instead you can use Schedule notification and random the time you want to show the notification.

Comment: But what is the best way to make sure every notification has an updated message from firebase? I don't want it to show the same message everyday

Comment: you can use notification push from firebase then, but you have to post the script write on javascript and run it with cloud function.  

fyi : cloud function is paid service from firebase.